# PhoneGap Apps Enquiries

Tags: mobile, cordova, web

I am new to mobile apps development. I came to know that phonegap make use of web-technologies like html, css and js to make cross-platform monile apps. I have some enquires on phone gap which I could not find some definite answers.

1. How does phonegap works? I know that it made use of web browsers without the browser border to run the app. But does running the app requires users to connect to the internet first?
2. When we develop a mobile app using phonegap for android, we can then use back the same html, css and js codes for building iphone, windows 7 phone, Blackberry apps by simply using the phonegap build platform that phonegap offers for developers?
3. Can web apps made using phonegap run on normal desktop web browser if the apps do not make use of native mobile devices such as accelerometer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **No**, an internet connection is not required for a [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) app. Simply put all html/js/css needed in the web folder and use local references.
2. **"Yes"**. You will have to reference different PhoneGap .js files for some of the platforms, but other than that you should be able to use the same web files. It is however possible that you will want to modify your app to better fit into each platform. For example, iOS includes a <strike>splash screen</strike> default image that you might want to handle differently on other platforms. These differences can either be handled by using the [device api](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_device_device.md.html) or as a part of your build pipeline.
3. **Yes**. if you don't use any mobile device specifics, it will run just as any other HTML5 app.

Comment: For 2. It is however possible that you will want to modify your app to better fit into each platform. For example, iOS includes a splash screen that you might have to handle differently on other platforms. How do we go about doing this? Is it by having checking conditions to check if the user is on iOS/android/blackberry and doing something to handle the differences? or can we simply disable all those splash screens no matter which platform the user is on? Any idea where can I have tutorials on explaining the things to look out for while programming cross platform apps on phonegap?

Comment: You can dynamically check what device you are on, and make your app react accordingly. I've updated the answer with more details.